# Could not Start Service -"contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 1"

Tags: apache, tomcat, batch-file

I have created a service and the service installed succesfully in the system and I could see it in the services.msc as well. Now when I try to start the service it gives me an error that "Windows cannot start service "X" in Local computer...contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 1." 
Now my service "X" was installed using a .bat file and to start the service it refers to a .exe file of type Commons Deamon Service Runner. This file is similar type of file which is also used internally to Apache service during Tomcat start up. 
Now I have searched for the root cause and found that it could be due to clash in port 80 due to which my service is not starting. Does any one have any idea how to modify my service port from 80 to anything else.
Thank you for your help!

Any info on Error code 1 would also be helpful!

Comment: I think you might be better posting this question in http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

Some other program like Skype must be listening on port 80; 
To resolve the error, close those programs and try starting the server again.
Now to change the default port for Apache - Modify the line "Listen 80" to "Listen 8080" (make sure you use port greater than 1023) in **httpd.conf** file